# Odds in a “reverse” raffle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

If in a raffle style drawing, but where you draw until one card or number is left, are the odds any different than when the first card drawn is the winner/loser?

Comment: No.  By symmetry, every number has an equal chance of being the one left.